# Spring MVC Multiaction Controller getParameter returning null

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC, need guidance

My **jsp** is like :

```
<form:form name="form1" method="post" action="input.htm?method=getHealth">
.......
<td >
<form:select path="envList">
<form:options items="${envList}"/>
</form:select>
</td>
```

My .java is like:

```
public class InputController extends MultiActionController {
    public ModelAndView getHealth(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        .......................
        String selectedEnv =request.getParameter("envList");
    }
}
```

Here I want to catch selected value from the dropdown to java,but
`request.getParameter("envList")` **is returning null**.
Please suggest how can I get selected value from jsp to .java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: mark some answers to questions of yours as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having a similar issue to this and I managed to fix it by catching the null early in my controller. Try this:

```
if(request.getParameter("form1") == null) { 
  return new ModelAndView();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@RequestParam("envList")` String envList  if you are using Spring 3 or annotations

```
public ModelAndView getHealth(@RequestParam("envList") String envList
    , HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    .......................
}
```

Above implemetation helps you to get the required value directly from  jsp .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should specify the `name` attribute of `<form:select`

Note that if you are not using the binding capabilities of spring (i.e. - spring auto-creating your command object based on request parameters), you can use the `<select>` tag (without any spring stuff)